# Login status maintain

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web site for test and forum in ASP.NET. I want to maintain user login status through out whole website till user logout. User can login any time, not necessary at a time when he opens web site. I have so many pages, so is there any easy way to check weather user is logged in or not on each page and display his status accordingly on each page.

Please help to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Use ASP.NET forms authentication.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SESSION` for the same.

nice explanation with good example [**here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net).

Answer (score 0):

you can use session  for this purpose if you are new to asp.net.

when user click on the login button, just save the userid or username or what ever you want in the session.

**On login button**

```
  Session["User"] = username.ToString();
   //you will get user id or username from the database. you can store anything in this session. its your wish.
```

Now on page load of master page just check that Session exists or not. Because page load of master page fires every time when ever a content page post back.

**OnPageload on master page:**

```
If(Session["user"] != null) // it should be first statement in page load event
{
  //your code
}
```

on logout button just remove the session or set session value to null.

Its the most easy and code less way to maintain the login of an user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement ASP.NET Membership. Membership basically swiftly creates a security system and you don't need to create your own.

Search for that to find a ton of resources and not a lot has changed since ASP.NET 2.0. For example, http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/10/5-minute-wonders-aspnet-membership.html

This will pretty rapidly allow you to have secured sections and user permissions.

In terms of your actual question, the only mechanism for determining if someone is logged in is with ASP.NET Membership. You can use Windows Authentication, but you won't easily get user information like their name without additional work.

If you use the ASP.NET Membership route, you'll be using Forms Authentication and this will have two states, Anonymous (not logged in) and Logged in.

To display of someone is logged in, you'll use the `LoginView` control. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/article.php/c13127/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginView-Control.htm

```
<asp:LoginView ID="ctlRightNavbar" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        Not logged in
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

In the code behind, you'll use the Membership details to get the user information, specifically with the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za59c2aa.aspx) class.

```
// get the logged in user
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
// user will be null if not logged in
if (user != null)
    // display the user details
    lblName.Text = user.UserName;
```